# Keep non-number characters in number counter string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textfield which allows users to input text. This can either be:

- Numbers, i.e. `16000`
- Number and other chars, i.e. `16,000+`

What I'm looking to do is for the numbers to count up, but the non number characters to remain as is.

Here's my approach so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.count').each(function () {
        $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
            Counter: $(this).text().replace(/\D/g, '')
        }, {
            duration: 3000,
            easing: 'swing',
            step: function (now) {
                $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
            }
        });
    });


    // add comma if number gets to thousands range
    function numberWithCommas(x) {
      return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    }

})
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js?ver=3.4.1'></script>

<span class=" count">16000</span>

<br>

<span class=" count">16,000+</span>
```

Notice how in the second instance (`16,000+`), the `+` sign and `comma` are removed when its finished counting.

I'm aware that I can output the non-number characters outside the `span`, i.e. `<p><span class="count">16,000</span>+</p>`, but for this to work, I'd:

1. Have to create a separate text field (one to hold the number value and the other for any text after it).
2. I cannot guarantee that the text will always be at the end of the text i.e. in some cases, it might be `£16,000 - £17,000 +`.

Is there a way to avoid all non-number chars from disappearing with minimal change to my markup?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this. The `£16,000 - £17,000 +` could be separated into 2 formatters, and animated separately, but for the sake of example, this should be ok

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.count').each(function() {
    const initial = $(this).text()
    const format = formatter(initial)

    $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
      Counter: format.value
    }, {
      duration: 3000,
      easing: 'swing',
      step: function(now) {
        $(this).text(format.revert(Math.ceil(now)));
      }
    });
  });
})

function formatter(str) {
  // const delimeter = '-'
  const char = 'x'
  const template = str.replace(/\d/g, char)
  const value = str.replace(/\D/g, '')

  function revert(val) {
    // need better solution
    const valStr = val.toString()
    let result = ''
    let index = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < template.length; i++) {
      const holder = template[i]
      if (holder === char) {
        result += valStr.slice(index, index + 1)
        index++
      } else {
        result += holder
      }
    }
    return result
  }
  return {
    template: template,
    value: value,
    revert: revert
  }
}
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js?ver=3.4.1'></script>

<span class=" count">16000</span>

<br>

<span class=" count">16,000+</span>
<br>

<span class="count">£16,000 - £17,000 +</span>
```